# I can't copy an xls file from one directory to other

Tags: python, copy

I'm trying to make a simple script which given a name it creates a folder and with in it 5 sub-folders and adds an typo-xls i have in other folder. I can create the folders and create an xls to be replaced later in this new folder but it seems it can't make the copyfile. What should be problem?

```
import os
import time
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
from os.path import join


print("Seja bem-vindo ao programa de Criação de Pastas.")
time.sleep(2)

#Qual a referência

ref=input("Qual a referência que pretende criar? (A,B ou C) : ")
if ref=='A':
    os.chdir(r"\\server\3Via\Referências A - Para Vender")
    dst=r"\\server\3Via\Referências A - Para Vender"
elif ref=='B':
    os.chdir(r"\\server\3Via\Referências B - Parceria")
    dst=r"\\server\3Via\Referências B - Parceria"
elif ref=='C':
    os.chdir(r"\\server\3Via\Referências C - Comprar")
    dst=r"\\server\3Via\Referências C - Comprar"
else :
    print("A referência inserida não está disponível! ")
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.exit()

folder=input("Digite o nome desejado para a pasta principal: ")
if not os.path.exists(folder):   os.makedirs(folder)


#Criação das Pastas 
os.chdir(folder)
os.makedirs('Citius')
os.makedirs('Portal das Finanças')
os.makedirs('Portal da Justiça')
os.makedirs('Racius e BP')
os.makedirs('Docs Importantes')
print("Pastas adicionadas com sucesso! ")
time.sleep(1)

#Copiar check-list para pasta

nomeficheiro='Check-list ' + folder[:-12]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(nomeficheiro)
workbook.close()

print("Ficheiro Criado com sucesso! ")

time.sleep(1)

src="\\server\3Via\...Docs Tipo"
shutil.copyfile(src=src+"/Check-list interna.xls", dst= dst+folder+nomeficheiro)
print("Check-list adicionada com sucesso! ")
time.sleep(5)
```

I just wanted it to replace the file that i already can create.

Comment: why do you mix `\ ` with `/` ? Maybe use `os.path.join(src, 'Check-list interna.xls')` to create path. OR at least display `src+"/Check-list interna.xls"` and `dst+folder+nomeficheiro` to see if you created correct pathes.

Answer (score 0):

## Point 1

first of all, I encourage you to use `pathlib` instead of strings.

Windows uses backslash, such as `C:\Users\Sam\AppData\`
Linux uses forward slash `C:/Users/Sam/AppData/`

The problem with using backslashes isn strings is that they have special meaning. For example, `C:\Users\nanny` will insert a new-line character `\n`.

With `pathlib.Path` You can use forward slashes, and not have that issue.

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path("C:/Users/nanny")
```

---

## Point 2

Make it possible to test your program without having
to type information at the command line over and over again. You, and others, will want to press one button
to make it go.

We don't want to see stuff like the following:

```
folder=input("Digite o nome desejado para a pasta principal: ")
```

---

## Point 3

One problem is "`/server/3Via/... Docs Type`" is not a valid path.

Another problem is that `parent_folder[:-12]` delete the last 12 characters from the folder name. I think that you want to ***USE*** the last 12 characters in the folder name, not ***delete*** the last 12. If the folder name is short, deleting the last 12 gets rid of the foldername completly. Use `parent_folder[-12:]` instead of `parent_folder[:-12]`

---

## Point 4

Do not trust relative paths and `chdir`. Just use absolute paths please; who only knows what the current working directory is at any given moment in time.

---

## Point 5

I wrote some code.
It makes the following directory tree:

```
server/
    3Via/
        ReferencesA-ForSale/
            abba_dabba_do_xyz/
                Check-listdabba_do_xyz.xlsx
                internalchecklist.xls
                Citius/
                Finance Portal/
                Important Docs/
                Portal of Justice/
                Racius and BP/
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
import pathlib as pl
import sys
import io

path_lookup = {
        'A':pl.Path("/server/3Via/ReferencesA-ForSale"),
        'B':pl.Path("/server/3Via/ReferencesB-Partnership"),
        'C':pl.Path("/server/3Via/ReferencesC-Buy")
    }

def pprint_path_lookup(path_lookup):
    with io.StringIO() as string__stream:
        for key in path_lookup.keys():
            print(
                key.ljust(4), path_lookup[key],
                file = string__stream,
                sep = ""
            )
        msg = string__stream.getvalue()
    return msg

class AI:
    def notify_without_seeking_response(self, *args, sep=" "):
        print(40 * "#")
        print(*args, sep=sep)
        print(40 * "#")
        
    def notify_and_get_response(self, *args):
        prompt = "\n".join(str(arg) for arg in args)
        prompt = prompt.strip()

        if "reference do you want to create?(A, B or C):" in prompt:
            response = "A"
        elif "desired name for the parent fold" in prompt:
            response = "abba_dabba_do_xyz"
        else:
            msg = "\ncomputer does not understand the prompt"
            msg += "\n"
            msg += prompt
            raise ValueError(msg)
        print(40*"#")
        print(prompt)
        print()
        print(response)
        print(40 * "#")
        return response
        
class Human:
    def notify_without_seeking_response(self, *args):
        print(*args)
        
    def notify_and_get_response(self, *args, sep=" "):
        prompt = sep.join(str(arg) for arg in args)
        choice = input(prompt)
        choice = choice.strip()
        return choice


def folder_creation_program(partner):
    return_data = dict()

    partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
        "Welcome to the Folder Creation program."
    )

    path = None
    for _ in range(20):
        options = pprint_path_lookup(path_lookup)
        ref = partner.notify_and_get_response(
            options,
            "What reference do you want to create?(A, B or C):"
        )
        path = path_lookup.get(ref)
        if path:
            break
        else:
            partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
                ref, "is invalid input"
            )

    if not path:
        msg = "failed to enter correct menu input after many tries"
        raise ValueError(msg)

    folder_name = partner.notify_and_get_response(
        "Enter the desired name for the parent folder:"
    )
    folder_name = folder_name.strip()
    folder_path = path / folder_name

    partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
        "Preparing to make:\n",
        folder_path
    )
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.makedirs(folder_path)
        partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
            "Successfully made:\n",
            folder_path
        )
    else:
        partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
            "Folder already exists:\n",
            folder_path
        )

    # Folder Creation
    child_folders = [
        'Citius',
        'Finance Portal',
        'Portal of Justice',
        'Racius and BP',
        'Important Docs'
    ]

    for child in child_folders:
        child_path = folder_path / child
        partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
            "Preparing to make folder:\n    ", child_path
        )
        if not os.path.isdir(child_path):
            os.makedirs(child_path)
        else:
            partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
                "folder\n    ", child_path,
                "\nalready exists. Leaving it alone."
            )
    partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
        "Folders added successfully!"
    )

    # create new file
    check_list_path = folder_path / ('Check-list' + folder_name[-12:] + ".xlsx")

    partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
        "Writing checklist to:\n    ",
        str(check_list_path)
    )

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(check_list_path)
    workbook.close()

    partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
        "File Created Successfully!\n    ",
        str(check_list_path)
    )

    # COPY .xlsx file to somewhere else
    src = check_list_path
    dst = folder_path / "internalchecklist.xls"
    shutil.copyfile(src=src, dst=dst)

    partner.notify_without_seeking_response(
        "Checklist copied successfully!\n    ",
        dst
    )

    return

folder_creation_program(AI())
```